# SSRS Use subset of available parameter values returned by query as the default parameter values

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, expression, default-value

SSRS 2012 - SharePoint Integrated Mode (SP 2010)

I have a stored procedure that returns a dataset of available values for an SSRS multi-valued parameter. Can I readily use a subset from it to populate the default values or must I create a second, similar, but smaller, dataset for the defaults ? If it can be done, many thanks in advance to anyone who can provide some insight and especially code samples to point me in the right direction.

The stored procedure returns a multi-column dataset (50+ items) in which values likely to be selected are calculated per other inputs and tagged to use as defaults ... dataset something like

Label / Value / UseAsDefault

White / 1 / N

Black / 2 / N

Green / 3 / Y

Blue / 4 / Y

Pink / 5 / N

and so on ...

This would seem a very simple thing to do, but I can't figure out how to create an expression to identify the subset of available values which are tagged as default values and then plug them in as the default values, i.e., per above how do I get Green and Blue be selected as defaults ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you could do this (other then use a separate dataset), because you would need to choose the specify default values option which only allows one value per line. If you had a fixed number that never changed then you could add a bunch of lines for default values and create an expression for each one which loops over the dataset and takes the first default if it's the first line, second if it's the second etc.

But that seems like way to much suffering when you can just create a separate dataset.

Comment: Thanks for the insights ! It appears that a separate dataset is the simplest answer. Current plan is to use the same sp to populate two datasets -- Param and ParamDFLT, with the ParamDFLT being filtered on the UseAsDefault flag. Then, managing the one sp should will produce consistent results, 'by default' the defaults will 'always' be a subset of the available values.